# How to deal with extremely high numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I have a program that deals with high numbers. However, when I try to use these numbers, I'll get summarized numbers, which I can't use. I need precise results. Is there a way to get rid of the summarization and use the ACTUAL numbers? By summarized numbers, I mean things like "1.5118532435192665e4".

Comment: **BigInt** is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole numbers larger than 2^53 - 1.

Comment: @PrathapReddy Thanks for the suggestion, but BigInt can't be used in the Math object, which I need, so it wouldn't work. Thanks for trying, though!